# Neural network with different input shapes

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow

I'm currently designing the architecture of a neural network for the colorization of grayscale images. Later on it should be able to colorize images with different sizes and different aspect ratios. I read that this would not be possible with a common CNN. I also read that the only options are downscaling the images to one specific size or to use a big fixed size (like 3000x3000px) and to fill the remaining space black. Both of these options don't seem to be that elegant. The first one is the opposite of what I want and the second would make the neural network slower.

Then I read about Fully Convolutional Networks and that this problem would not exist there. This would be great if it really works. I would like to know why this special network can deal with different input shapes. And maybe you could show me some tensorflow code of such a network.

By the way, I thought about an Autoencoder combined with a GAN for the architecture.

I know that this question is very general, but I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't have experience with this particular problem, but have you thought about training your model on splitted versions of photos? Rather than one big size that you apply to a picture, you could train a smaller version and apply it multiple times on different parts of the picture.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this would not work when the number of pixels is odd and the colors would probably not match that well when combining those segmented images. But thank you very much anyway!

Comment: That would probably cause blocking effect